# How to make an inline svg clickable in html/css to use onclick in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an inline svg in my html:

```html
<svg id="nav-search-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32.2 32.2"><path d="M19 0C11.8 0 6 5.8 6 13c0 3.1 1.1 5.9 2.9 8.2l-8.6 8.6c-0.5 0.5-0.5 1.4 0 2 0.5 0.5 1.4 0.5 2 0l8.6-8.6C13.1 24.9 15.9 26 19 26c7.2 0 13-5.8 13-13S26.2 0 19 0zM19 24C12.9 24 8 19.1 8 13S12.9 2 19 2 30 6.9 30 13 25.1 24 19 24z"/></svg>
```

I want to make another element visible or hidden on clicking the svg. Here's the javascript I use to do this:

```js
let searchIcon = document.querySelector('#nav-search-icon')
let searchBar = document.querySelector('#search-bar')

searchIcon.onclick = function() {
    if (searchBar.style.visibility === 'hidden') {
        searchBar.style.visibility = 'visible'
    } else if (searchBar.style.visibility === 'visible') {
        searchBar.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    }
}
```

The javascript code does not work. I think the reason it does not work is that the svg element is not clickable (the icon of my mouse does not change from pointer to hand on hovering over the svg). I've tried adding `pointer-events="all"` to the `svg` element and also to the `path` element inside the `svg` element. I've also tried adding `pointer-events: all;` to the CSS. None of this worked.

**EDIT: ** I've looked at questions about making the svg link clickable (by adding an `<a>` tag outside the svg element). I don't want to have a link to another page. I want onclick to work for the svg element.

Comment: What about using a more modern method, like `searchIcon.addEventListener('click', function () { ... });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few changes to the `JS`, but wrapped the `SVG` inside of an `<a>` tag and added the `onclick()` to that, like so:

```js
searchClick = function() {
  let searchIcon = document.querySelector('#nav-search-icon')
  let searchBar = document.querySelector('#search-bar')
  if (searchBar.style.display === 'none') {
    searchBar.style.display = 'block'
  } else {
    searchBar.style.display = 'none'
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="searchClick();"><svg id="nav-search-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32.2 32.2"><path d="M19 0C11.8 0 6 5.8 6 13c0 3.1 1.1 5.9 2.9 8.2l-8.6 8.6c-0.5 0.5-0.5 1.4 0 2 0.5 0.5 1.4 0.5 2 0l8.6-8.6C13.1 24.9 15.9 26 19 26c7.2 0 13-5.8 13-13S26.2 0 19 0zM19 24C12.9 24 8 19.1 8 13S12.9 2 19 2 30 6.9 30 13 25.1 24 19 24z"/></svg></a>

<div style="display: none;" id="search-bar">
  <input width="200" value="Search"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Would be interested in using `jQuery` for this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm currently learning web development. This is my first website. I don't want to make big jumps before I master the basics. Thanks anyways

Comment: [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) is just a basic javascript library that helps make some things like this a bit easier and writing less code.

Comment: @Huzaifa I just made a few changes (to the `javascript`) that should hopefully work for you now. Please give it a try and let me know!

Comment: For anyone else with the same problem, my main mistake was using the `visibility` property instead of the `display` property. Everything else was working fine. And please use `addEventListener()`.